# Get node from UrlName in Umbraco

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, umbraco

I am working on an `Umbraco` set up (`Umbraco 7`) and I need to be able to load a node from a `node.UrlName`.

I tried `Xpath` but that didn't work. Here is my `xpath`:

```
var facNode = umbraco.NodeFactory.Node.GetNodeByXpath("/*[@UrlName='" + urlName + "']");
```

I have also tried a few variations of this without `/`, with `//` and just looking for an `id` instead of a `UrlName`.

This seems to be something fairly simple but I seem to be missing something. I am pretty new to `Umbraco` so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Id there a better way than `xpath`? What class should I be using for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Umbraco - Select node by URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450782/umbraco-select-node-by-url)

Comment: You can use uQuery ,  Node node = uQuery.GetNodeByUrl("/home.aspx");

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for. I was hoping to get the item from the UrlName property. The item url will not work for what I need to do.

Comment: As far as suggesting a better way, can you provide some more context? E.g. why do you _only_ have the `urlName`. Where are you executing this code, in a view, controller, console app?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple of things here. Firstly, the xpath is case-sensitive, so you need to target `@urlName` not `@UrlName`.

Also it's worth pointing out that trying to locate a node by the urlName property isn't a very good strategy because multiple nodes could have an identical urlName property. This is possible because Umbraco only insists that the urlName property is unique where the node shares the same parent.

This makes sense because (e.g. when grouping news/blog articles) you may want a node called October under a node called 2014 but also a node called October under a parent called 2013. In this scenario, your xpath would locate both October nodes and therefore not work.

As far as a btter way, it depends on what the context is and what you are trying to achieve. You certainly should be avoiding using the `umbraco.NodeFactory.Node` as from Umbraco 4.8 the standard has been to use the `IPublishedContent` interface which is arguably more flexible.